# Suggest me some good bicycles

Tags: commuter

I do not know if my question is aligned with the rules of this community, but I have the following requirements before buying a bicycle:

1. Must have minimum repair needs.
2. Must be comfortable for both off-road and city commuting.

Please suggest me some good bicycles which I can buy. I will do cycling in the summer to keep fit and have fun. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Define "off-road". There's a world of difference between flat gravel trails and double black mtb trails. Also, how far is your commute?

Comment: Sorry. By "off-road" I meant straight gravel paths with small ups and down. The road can be wet and muddy (again not much). I did not mean very steep mountain jumping or doing stunts. My daily commute is less than 10 miles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"minimal repair" means they are less likely to break down.  It doesn't mean "no maintenance"     A low-maintenance bike would have

- Enclosed chain case OR belt drive
- One gear
- Puncture-resistant tyres
- Hub-Dynamo-driven lights

You might wish for gears, in which case an Internally Geared Hub is beneficial, though these do need oil changes yearly.

Your bike will be more reliable if it is maintained and stored inside, in the warm and dry when not in use.

---

A commuting bike will have:

- No suspension
- Full Mudguards / fenders to keep the roadspray down
- Facility for carrying your stuff, whether that be a rack, pannier(s), basket, or similar.
- Lights

---

An off-road bike depends more on the terrain.   A flat gravel path does not need anything different from your ideal commuter bike, whereas steep climbs/descents and big jumps/landings may require more suitable bike designs.

Off road bikes tend to make for poor commuters, because there's only so-much power available and the losses to suspension are significant.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It really helps and I accepted your answer. By "off-road" I meant straight gravel paths with small ups and down. The road can be wet and muddy (again not much). I did not mean very steep mountain jumping or doing stunts. My daily commute is less than 10 miles. Do you think fat bikes are a good choice for me or not?